# Are MongoDB ids sorted by default and also whether all ids are unique or not?

Tags: android, mongodb, sorting, binary-search

I am having a doubt in MongoDB for my Android app, that first is "_id" which is created by default in Mongo unique or not, I thought it must be unique but I read it somewhere that there are cases that it will not be unique so how to make it unique for default?

Second doubt I have is actually in my app my when user upvotes a question then I store that question's "_id" in user_upvotes collection with user_id and push that "_id" in an array. When I load all current questions I have to check it in user's upvotes array that whether this user has upvoted it or not by matching that question "_id" with all values inside users array.

My question is that I thought that to decrease this searching time if I know that if all "_ids" are created in sorted order by mongoDB by default then I will use binary search algorithm to decrease the time but I don't know whether it is in sorted order or not.

Also if MongoDB itself does not create unique "_ids" by default then I cannot use binary search and have to make myself unique ids for the questions?

Comment: i have serious doubts too it is hard to write an application when all the punctuation characters are missing and it will be hard to read and maintain too and because of that i refuse to answer a question no effort was put into. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The default `_id` types for MongoDB collections is `ObjectId`, which is [guaranteed to be unique](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-objectid) within that collection.
2. Pushing `_id`s in an array does not sort the array. The array is sorted in the order of the items you have pushed to it.
3. Generally, you'll be better off querying MongoDB, and therefore relying on its searching algorithms, rather than implementing a binary search yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for helping me out here, actually i have to show user 10 recent questions per page now don't you think that for each 10 questions i will look for user_id from where i will query on array that whether it contains that questions id or not. Or instead of repeating this step for every 10 questions what i will do is i will fetch 10 recent questions and in parallel with that i will fetch user's whole upvote array now in callback i will check with binary search that whether all 10 questions are in that array or not.

Comment: actually problem was for evry 10 questions i dont wanna see whether it is inside the array or not.

Comment: Hi @amanverma. I'm not sure I understand, but this sounds like a different question than the above, one that should be posted separately. If you feel my answer is adequate for your question, please mark it as resolved ;-).

Comment: i mean you are telling me to query database for every recent post that whether i have liked the post or not but in my case i am telling first fetch all my up_voted posts and now i have this array binary search inside this array to see whether recent posts have upvoted by me or not ??

Comment: Your array will not be sorted, other than by the order in which you added items to it. You will have to do a full search of the contents of the array to see if an item is in it or not.

Comment: yeah but dont you think as mongos _ids are created in increasing order so my array will be in ascending order ?? tell me if i am thinking wrong ??

Comment: I think you can make this assumption, yes

Comment: Glad I could help—and again, if this answers your question, remember to mark the answer!